# How do I fix this error: Warning: invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: menus, admin, errors, admin-menu, core

I recently moved a wordpress install from my local instance to a dev server.  For the move, I installed a clean version of wordpress 3.4, moved exact duplicates of the file structre, and used the import / export feature to bring the posts in.

I then went in and set the necessary widgets, and settings.  I've done this 100 times, and never had this problem.  Here is the error:

**Warning**: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in **/home/content/46/9411746/html/dev/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php** on line **1285**

It only appears in the admin menu.  I see it when I try to add a widget, change a setting, work with menus, or update meta data for a post.  It pops up all over the admin menu.

Here is the function triggering the error in includes/plugin.php

```
function remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ) {
global $menu;

foreach ( $menu as $i => $item ) {
    if ( $menu_slug == $item[2] ) {
        unset( $menu[$i] );
        return $item;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

I'm using appearance > menus and have two registered here in functions.php here:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-nav' => __( 'Main Header Navigation', 'kyosay' ),
      'footer-nav' => __( 'Footer Navigation', 'kyosay' )
    )
);
}
```

I am doing some other customization of the admin panel, reordering some menu items and eliminating others that my clients don't need.  I can include that code if you think it's relevant.

Since this issue is triggered in core, I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.  *NOTE:*  The issue is not happening on my local build.  Thoughts?

**Edit: added remove_menu_items code from functions.php for reference**

```
function remove_menu_items() {
remove_menu_page('link-manager.php'); // Links
remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menu_items' );
```

**Update:**
I have eliminated functions.php as the source of this issue.  It seems to be triggered on Ajax events (dragging a new widget to a sidebar, updating a meta-box, etc.  I'm going to uninstall and reinstall and see if it's still happening.  Could this have something to do with the web host (godaddy) ?  It's not showing up on my local build at all.

Comment: Is `$menu` an array when you call the function? Did you test that?

Comment: how do I test that without editing core?  sry haven't had an issue like this before, not very experience w/ php debugging

Comment: It is fine to edit core files for debugging purposes, like doing a `print_r($menu);` to see what the variable looks like. Just make sure everything is back to normal when you finish debugging.

Comment: ok I got the print_r($menu); to work.  I took out the `foreach()` call and replaced it with the `print_r($menu)`.  Here is the paste of the output:  http://pastebin.com/LSjLxHVC

Comment: That doesn't look like it would cause that error...

Comment: I have definitely been baffled by the error.  It's interesting because there is nothing different in my code locally, but I don't get the error there.  I think it has something to do with the order I set up the menus.. something got borked in moving to the /dev install.  I'm trying to avoid reinstalling but I might have to..

Answer (score 7):

This usually happens when you are trying to do admin navigation stuff and you aren't hooked into `admin_menu`. If you hook in before that, `$menu` hasn't been created yet.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_add_menu');

function my_plugin_add_menu(){
    $ptype = 'my_post_type';
    $ptype_obj = get_post_type_object( $ptype );
    add_submenu_page( 'my-menu-item', $ptype_obj->labels->name, $ptype_obj->labels->all_items, $ptype_obj->cap->edit_posts, "edit.php?post_type=$ptype" );
}
```

Comment: I tried removing all the admin nav stuff and the issue still remained.  Here is a paste of the relevant functions.php code - do you see anything there?  http://pastebin.com/2f1AaxPU

Comment: Are you using `admin_init` or `admin_menu`? There is a difference...

Comment: `add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );`

Comment: I'm talking about for when you call 'remove_menu_page'

Comment: added the remove_menu_page code above

Comment: So, now you should go back and read my answer again, and see how it applies to the code you just gave me.

Comment: Ok - I edited the code and moved the add_action(...) above the function.  I am still getting the error, however.  Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: No. you are using `admin_init`. When `admin_init` happens, the menus haven't been loaded. It isn't until `admin_menu` happens that `$menu` is loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3791/discussion-between-timshutes-and-chacha102)

Comment: I used admin_menu instead of admin_int and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with wordpress, just added an if statement to check the argument as follows

```
if(is_array($thearray)){
    //use $thearray here
}
```

and the warning was gone!!

Comment: This isn't really a problem with WordPress. It is problem with PHP, and checking the value as you have done will solve certain 'notice' issues. It is not clear that it will solve this one.  In fact, if `$thearray` has to be set for some function to work, then it doesn't solve the problem it just masks the message. It is not possible to tell if this a fix or not without knowing exactly what triggers the notice.

Comment: i was looking for a way to silence the warning on my blog because it was making the page ugly, and i get your point, but why does it behave this way? The reason i was checking is to make sure $thearray is an array, which indeed is... so? I am really puzzled. Checking again...

Comment: Yes, there are cases where you just need to silence the warning but there are also cases where this indicates a deeper problem, a problem where things might actually be broken. That is my worry.